# Creating an Ant target to run a java class which is within a jar

Tags: java, ant

I working on a problem which involves a large jar that includes many different source files.  One of those source files is a test class, and I want to run that test class from a different project.
This test class has a main class and should work with the arguments being passed to it from ant. 
Although the problem seems to be the class path.  I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit.framework.TestCase
```

This is my target stripped out.

```
    <target name="lookup-excute" description="Runs a Look up on all event files in the input folder.">
    <java classname="com.testing.LookupTest" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <arg value="${events.location}"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="..${file.separator}jars${file.separator}testing.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: You need to put the path of the junit JAR in your classpath as well, or package it with your code (not recommended, since it's only for testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general: when you have a ClassNotFound, then you should locate the class in one of your jar files. You just open a jar (with the same tool you use for zip files) and try to browse junit/framework and find TestCase.class jar.

When you don't see the class in any of your jars, you search the internet (or [jarfinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/)) for the class name. Then you know you need an additional jar, like junit in this case. When you know you want "junit" you download it from home page or in most cases easily from maven: [maven search](http://search.maven.org/).

I don't know if you may run junit tests directly. Commonly you use [junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) for them.